# MSIX Installed WPF application that uses Azure SSO will not launch

Tags: wpf, azure, visual-studio, .net-5, msix

I am new to creating an MSIX installer and hosting it on Azure.

Question: Why will a WPF application that is installed with an MSIX installer not launch?

Details: I have a WPF application built on .NET 5 that logs users into our Azure SQL database with SSO. So, when the application launches, it will first open Chrome to allow the user to enter their AAD credentials. Once that step is complete, the application will launch. I followed Tim Corey's walkthrough on how to create an MSIX installer here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4t2TI8ImwMY

I am able to build the application and the MSIX installer. The MSIX package is created on my local and I am able to launch the application's executable from the release folder. I am able to run the MSIX installer and install the application and I see it in both the Start Menu and the WindowsApps folder. But, when I go to run the application, it will not launch. I am not getting any error and I do not see the process start in the Task Manager.

Considering there is no error or response when I try to launch the application, I am not even sure where to begin troubleshooting this. I have tried building and publishing the MSIX installer with Visual Studio in admin mode and I check the Windows Event Viewer, but did not see any errors related to the application. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like there is a resource missing. Maybe a dll that has not been included in MSIX? but this is just a guess. It could be that you are not utilising data templates and instead using strings to show content in your app. Could you give us more info? Is there a custom step when it comes to launching your app? a jpeg for a splash screen?

Comment: Try to use Process Monitor, filter by the process/executable name, and see if anything pops up. Errors in trying to load a dll or something like this should be easy to spot.

Another way is to debug the app directly from Visual Studio? I assume you can do this with an MSIX package built with the VS built-in support. But here is also an example of how you can do it with the MSIX packaging support from Advanced Installer.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PhJ1r-kfT0&ab_channel=AdvancedInstaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is nothing wrong with the way I created the MSI project and published it. The problem appears to be with my computer. Other users in the organization were able to install the MSI package and run the application.